# wso2 identity server 5.3.0 users and multi tenancy configuration guidelines with Oauth2 if possible

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Can anyone help me out with a guideline to configure a specific Service Provider to a specific Tenant only, i.e. exclude all tenants from accessing the specific Service Provider.

I tried creating Service Provider using the guidelines from:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Configuring+a+Service+Provider
by the way I used oauth2 with Implicit flow.

Then I created multiple tenant domains like:
abc.com
xyz.com

I created rob under abc.com tenant and sam under xyz.com.

when I use url(https://localhost:9443/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=my_client_id_was_here&redirect_uri=my_redirect_uri_was_here) to login, login page showed up but I was ABLE to login using both rob and sam credentials.

What I want is to do is to restrict users of only one specific domain/tenant to access my service provider.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To restrict a service provider to a specific tenant, you have to create that service provider inside that tenant. So to create a SP inside "abc.com". Log into that tenant using a tenant user (rob@abc.com) and create the service provider inside it.

Comment: Firstly Thank you very much to @Jayanga Kaushalya

Comment: I have created a tenant for a specific domain, while creating a tenant we would have to fill in a admin username and password for the specific tenant. I logged in using the tenant admin userid[at]domainname.ext and password. Then I created a SP as answered above and it totally worked.

Comment: @rv.comm Nice to hear it is working. Please accept the answer if you think this solves your issue.